# Gunicorn Service Failed To Start Due To Permission Denied

Tags: python, gunicorn, systemd

I followed a [Digital Ocean guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-22-04) to set up Flask application to run with Gunicorn and Nginx (not there yet). But when trying to start the application, got the following error:

```
* web-project.service - Gunicorn Instance To Serve web-project Project
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/web-project.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2023-09-06 05:05:09 UTC; 5s ago
    Process: 4540 ExecStart=/var/www/web-project/pv310/bin/gunicorn --bind unix:web-project.sock --workers 3 --umask 007 backend.uwsgi:application (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
   Main PID: 4540 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Sep 06 05:05:09 or1010051244158.corp.adobe.com systemd[1]: Started Gunicorn Instance To Serve Web Project.
Sep 06 05:05:09 or1010051244158.corp.adobe.com systemd[4540]: web-project.service: Failed to execute command: Permission denied
Sep 06 05:05:09 or1010051244158.corp.adobe.com systemd[4540]: web-project.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /var/www/web-project/pv310/bin/gunicorn: Permission denied
Sep 06 05:05:09 or1010051244158.corp.adobe.com systemd[1]: web-project.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Sep 06 05:05:09 or1010051244158.corp.adobe.com systemd[1]: web-project.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

This is the **web-project.service** file located at `/etc/systemd/system/web-project.service`

If I were to run the application without `User=www-data` and `Group=www-data`, it seem to run fine, but I would like to run them as the `www-data` user.

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn Instance To Serve Web Project
After=network.target

[Service]
User=www-data
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/web-project
Environment="PATH=/var/www/web-project/pv310/bin"
ExecStart=/var/www/web-project/pv310/bin/gunicorn --bind unix:web-project.sock --workers 3 --umask 007 backend.uwsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I modified the `/var/www/web-project` directory and `/var/www/web-project/pv310` with correct ownership and permission

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/web-project
```

I am able to run the application directly with `gunicorn`

```
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8080 backend.uwsgi:application
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out by creating a new user account for testing.

I realized that this was running on a virtual Python environment (`venv`), and how things are symlink on *nix systems...

- The `gunicorn` module even if you execute as a binary, it will still call Python.
- The `python` (or `python3.x`) in the `bin` directory of the `venv` is only a symlink to the actual Python binary of where you install or compiled it.
- The user used to run the service will need to have permission to that actual binary as well

During normal installation, it usually install to `/bin` or `/usr/bin`, and provide the correct permission. But since it was compiled from source, it was missing permission on one of the parent folder (even though it has permission on the binary itself).

Once I make sure the user have permission to all parent directories and the binary, it worked fine.